# Add string before item in listbox

Tags: c#, string, listbox

I have a method that fills up a listbox with properties. I would like to add a string before the properties value to clearify what it is.

```
        listBox1.Items.Add(person.Name);
        listBox1.Items.Add(person.Phone);
        listBox1.Items.Add(person.City);
```

Is it possible to add something in the above code that will show:

```
Name: (person.Name)
Phone: (person.phone)
```

When the result shows in the listbox?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the person itself and format it in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("Name: {0}", person.Name));
```

Comment: Worked prefectly! Thanks! I´ll accept this as an answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
  listBox1.Items.Add("Name :" + person.Name);
```

Or:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("Name : {0}", person.Name);
```